# Weird behaviour of Java logging statement

Tags: java, linux, logging, log4j, slf4j

Using **log4j with Sl4j** and ran into a weird issue, I have following log statement.

```
log.trace("Foo Request object value : {} foo params: {}" , foo==null, foo);
```

If foo has a bar value, it prints below in my local logging.

```
Foo Request object value : false foo params: bar
```

But when I deploy my code to production, it prints below:

```
Foo Request object value : false
```

**Notice above it doesn't even print the "foo params:" which is the string in my logging statement, forget about printing the param value of it**.

Also as foo is not null, that's the reason first param value **false** is printed, then why that object itself is not printed as part of 2nd param and more interestingly its corresponding string in logging statement also not printed.

In short, I wanted to understand why this is happening in the production environment and how can I make it work.

Comment: this sounds more like a caching/deploy issue rather than a logger issue

Comment: How it could be a deployment issue, if half line is coming but not the entire one.. and sorry caching one also I didn't understand.. could you please elaborate

Comment: my point was that may be you have deployed some time ago that half statement and  you don't remember about it?

Comment: @Eugene, no this is not the case, this entire statement was written and deployed single time only...

Comment: understood, this is _very_ weird in this case

Comment: @Eugene, that's the reason i mentioned weird in my post subject :).. its making my debugging in production system hell :|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191193/discussion-between-amit-khandelwal-and-eugene).

Comment: Have you set the default logger level to trace?
You can do so by setting a property in your properties file
`org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel = trace`

Comment: `half ` line in my logging statement having `trace` level is still coming, and why it requires to set the default log level to `trace`?

Comment: Did you try to decompile this code and check the string in the resulting class files?

Comment: Is it a standalone app or deployed inside a container? Does it include any other framework / libraries? Do you perform a new build for production? Do you use production-specific flags?

Comment: @MarinosAn , it's a standalone app and it's a java heavy app and uses framework like spring, jersey etc..

Comment: The output is 32 characters. Is it possible, that your target environment does not support lines longer than 32 characters? I know some older or specific environments have really strange limitations. What is you target environment? Windows Server? Linux Server IBM Host?

Comment: Your problem is related to your production environnement: system, java configuration, log access (at least). We can't help you without specific information about thoses. 
Did you check you have deployed the right version of your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try your build after maven shading the log libraries,many a times server side libraries take preference over the one's you mentioned leading to issues like version conflicts or unexpected behaviour in code like in your's case.
If possible please try out this option,in worst case if this doesn't work it would rule out one of the possibilities and in such weird cases I find it best to rule out as many possible cases before narrowing out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you run the below command on your class and post the output from the production.

```
javap -verbose <YourClassName>.class
```

With the output, we should be able to see how the class was assembled.

***PS:*** *Based on how you have deployed, you may need to unpack your jar file and then run the above command on the extracted class.*